# Getting the Mac addresses of all devices in a building

Tags: gps, wireless, mac-address

Me and my team we are working on a project for University. Our goal is to prevent people that are outside of a specific range to enter our wireless network. Lets say u are sitting in Starbucks and next to that there is another coffee shop. If u are a starbucks customer you will be able to enter the network and surf the internet. If you are sitting at the coffee shop next to starbucks though u will still see the wireless on your device but you won't be able to connect, or if you connect you will get kicked automatically.

My question is . Is there a way to get all the mac addresses of all devices in a specific area (Sturbucks building) and then only allow those to enter the wireless network. If thats possible through a mapping of a network or a device we don't care. We just want a way. And also is there a way to determine where exactly is a device,its location ? With or without a GPS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of all your questions is: NO.

- You cannot get the mac adresses of foreign networks (sturbucks) without hacking the routers
- You cannot get the location of a device in general. If the device is connected to your router, hotspot, Wlan, etc, you then could know that. In generall  you cannot get the device GPS position, only if the user of the device allows that.

The other location possibility is the cell tower the user is logged in, that does not help you because you will not get the info in wich GSM cell the user is connected, without hacking the GSM network, and probably sturbucks and the uni has the same cell tower.

Remain wlan locationing: Here the same, the device might know it but you not.

Update:

There is one solution I remember now. Remeber the waste bins installed in London on public roads, they track when user pass by. They behave like WLAN devices, and track the mac adress. You could create such a system, maybe you cannot buy that. And place it near the entrance of the shop. Users which pass by have their mac adress recorded, you send that mac to your special wlan router and add that macs dynamically. Another possibility would be the use of bluetopot but this has to be enabled on the phone:

Look at the system how Apple's low energy blue tooth "location beacons" work: It is build for indoor positioning. you can triangulate the signal strength of a device. But probably the effort is beyond your project budget. (And still the useres woul dhave to enable blue tooth)

Comment: Using a Username/ password is not efficient and i don't accept that solution. Imaging each time someone comes to have to type a different username and password. Also with that solution you are suggesting anyone can enter even if he's not a customer. Sorry but if you can't help why would you even waste your time and my time to answer.. Thank you

Comment: updated my answer, removed proposal. Just answered your questions. Further comsider looking also at server fault page.

Comment: That's way better. But I just want to add that I will design the network for the coffee shop(Starbucks). I ll be the administrator of that network and basically my goal is to check if the people connected on my network are actually my customers and they are in my shop and not just random people from outside. Hacking is allowed also if it's the only way to protect my network from other people (Not customers)

Comment: Ah ok, design for teh side of starbucks: that is an important info, because the university can register their students. for coffee shop, you cannot. The bars I know have a verry weak signal outside. So practically solved by weak signal

Comment: Can u explain a bit more? What do u mean the bars you know ?

Comment: The restaurants, bar, clubs etc in my city have a very weak signal outside. The walls are built with massive stone, concrete or bricks . This also could be a solution for you, if the walls are massive.

Comment: Crap . I dont want it only for buildings with massive walls but also with  big yard or something. :/

Comment: There is one solution I remember now. Remeber the waste bins installed in London on public roads, they track when user pass by. They behave like WLAN devices, and track the mac adress. You could create such a system, maybe you cannot buy that. And place it near the entrance of the shop. Users which pass by have their mac adress recorded, you send that mac to your special wlan router and add that macs dynamically. Another possibility would be the use of bluetopot but this has to be enabled on the phone.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. You really helped. I would research how the trash bins worked more and hope it will solve our problem.